# Как привязать контекст данной функции, чтобы он не был равен window

Tags: javascript, php, битрикс

Есть функция

```
JCSmartFilter.prototype.showDropDownPopup = function(element, popupId) {
    var contentNode = element.querySelector('[data-role="dropdownContent"]');
    console.log('showDropDownPopup this element: ');
    console.log(element);
    BX.PopupWindowManager.create("smartFilterDropDown"+popupId, element, {
        bindElement: element,
        autoHide: true,
        offsetLeft: 0,
        offsetTop: 3,
        overlay: false,
        draggable: {restrict:true},
        closeByEsc: true,
        content: contentNode
    }).show();
};
```

вызывается она следующим образом:

```
<div class="bx_filter_select_block" onclick="smartFilter.showDropDownPopup(this, '<?=CUtil::JSEscape($key)?>')">
```

Далее, при переходе на любой элемент всплывающего окна происходит перезагрузка и выводит результаты фильтра, но всплывающее окно привязывается к window и улетает на верхний левый угол:

```
JCSmartFilter.prototype.selectDropDownItem = function(elem, controlId) {
    this.keyup(BX(controlId));
};
```

```
JCSmartFilter.prototype.keyup = function(input) {
    setTimeout(BX.delegate(function(){
        this.reload(input);
    }, this), 500);
};
```

Каким образом зафиксировать this функции `showDropDownPopup`?

Comment: А в чем проблема? вы не же используете `this` в функции? вы передаете контекст из темплейта в виде параметра. По идее он будет равен самому элементу, на котором висит слушатель, т.е. `div.bx_filter_select_block`

Comment: Если я правильно понял, то можно использовать метод call, который первым параметром принимет объект, который станет this-ом для функции, а вторым - аргументы. https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_function_call.asp